# How can I stop the execution of my promise based on the boolean value of my prop?

Tags: reactjs, promise

I have a promise that looks like this:

```
fetchDetails().then(() => fetchNextDetails()).catch(() => routeToErrorPage());
```

I have a prop called `isFetchError`, whose value is the result of `fetchDetails()`. If `this.props.isFetchError` is true, I want it to `routeToErrorPage()` and not execute `fetchNextDetails()`. Is this possible? When I try using `isFetchError` in the catch, I'm given console errors.

I understand that this is not generally how a catch works, but this is unfortunately the way this app was written and cannot afford a large refactor.

Update
My service call looks like this:

```
export function fetchDetails() {
    const url = sensitiveData;
    const types = [GET_REQUEST, GET_SUCCESS, GET_FAILURE];
    const params = {};
    const promise = {...config, method: 'get', url, params};
    return {types, promise};
}
```

Reducer:

```
case GET_FAILURE:
            return {...state, isFetchError: true};
```

Reducer returns isFetchError: true when GET_FAILURE action is fired. GET_FAILURE is fired when service call fails. My state of isFetchError does change correctly. I just want to use its result to make sure the second call of my promise doesn't execute.

Comment: You can have a global implementation with service workers. Try something like this out https://medium.com/@adactio/handling-redirects-with-a-service-worker-514a310863cf

Comment: Can you also show us exactly how it's implemented with `isFetchError`

Comment: Take a look at this https://techbeacon.com/app-dev-testing/how-use-service-workers-progressive-web-apps

Comment: @Train I have updated the description with more details.

Comment: What's going on? There's no service call and `fetchDetails()` returns a javascript plain object, not Promise. Even the property of the object `.promise` isn't a Promise - it's another javascript plain object.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 middleware handles the promise. Anyway, what I'm really trying to get to the root of is if it's possible to use the isFetchError prop in the catch. My service calls work just fine and my promise executes. I'm just trying to stop the second service call from executing with the result of the isFetchError.

Comment: Emily, for middleware to handle the promise, there must be a promise in the first place .... and maybe there is, somewhere, but not in the code you  posted.

Comment: That is why I recommended a service worker. Everything is done from one location, you don't have to change the current code. You can intercept errors and redirect from the service worker without refactoring existing code if you don't have the time for that.

Answer (score 0):

After researching a bit more, I've come to the conclusion it isn't possible to catch from the value of a prop. However, I've found using something of this sort works:

```
fetchDetails.then(() => {
 if (isFetchError){
     throw new Error(‘go to catch’)
  } else {
    return fetchNextDetails()
  }
}).catch(routeToErrorPage());
```

Comment: You should be seeking a solution in which the Promise returned by `fetchDetails()` follows its error path on failure. Then, the behaviour you seek will be given by  `fetchDetails().then(fetchNextDetails).catch(routeToErrorPage);`
without needing to store state in some commonly accessible outer member.